# How do I deal with double quotes?

Tags: quotes

I'm writing a genre essay on the novel Breaking Dawn, and the beginning of the quote I want to use starts with quotation marks, like so:

"My venom," he answered as he pushed the plunger down.

So when I quote that would it look something like this?:

"'My venom,' he answered as he pushed the plunger down."

if not, please do show me how it would be done, and if it helps, the quote I'm using is on page 354.

Comment: Your example (with outer double quotes and inner single quotes) is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Quotes within a quote are just a matter of reversing either the double or single speech marks, whichever was used first. (Brits tend to use ".." while Americans seem more likely to use '...')

So you are correct in your statement. It should be:

> "'My venom,' he answered as he pushed the plunger down."

Or, for the Americans:

> '"My venom," he answered as he pushed the plunger down.'

[The Economist Style Guide](http://www.economist.com/style-guide/inverted-commas-quotation-marks)